# windows login name by IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is Null .net 6

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-5.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyEdJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvlJG.png)

and add services in startup .
but when i make this process on core 5 ,this process is Done .

Comment: Post any code and errors as *text* in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET 6 Microsoft has removed the Startup.cs class. Be sure configure the services in Program.cs in .NET 6 like below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```